# Apache SSO with kerberos and Active Directory error

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, active-directory, ldap, kerberos

I have this scenario: a windows 2008 R2 Domain and a linux server (CentOs) with Apache.

I need to configure SSO using kerberos in order to permit our internal client using IE or Chrome to authenticate on a website without asking for a password.

In order to do this i follow this tutorial https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Kerberos_Windows_Interoperability.

My Apache conf file for the site is:

```
AuthType Kerberos
AuthName "Kerberos Login"
KrbAuthRealms <MYREALM>
KrbServiceName HTTP/OTRS5@<MYREALM>
Krb5Keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
KrbMethodNegotiate On
KrbMethodK5Passwd Off
KrbSaveCredentials Off
KrbVerifyKDC Off
Require valid-user
```

Now when I try to connect to the site I receive a 401 code.

On error.log I found :

```
kerb_authenticate_user entered with user (NULL) and auth_type Kerberos
Acquiring creds for HTTP/OTRS5@<MYREALM>
Verifying client data using KRB5 GSS-API  
Client didn't delegate us their credential
```

On journalctl:

```
GSSAPI Error: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Server not found in Kerberos database)
```

I'm totally clueless about it.

Can you help me?
Regards
   Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue.
1) I have enable the kerberos loggin on the DC https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262177

2) After check again the login I found this error under the Security Log:
The KDC encountered duplicate names while processing a Kerberos authentication request. The duplicate name is HTTP/ (of type DS_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME). This may result in authentication failures or downgrades to NTLM. In order to prevent this from occuring remove the duplicate entries for HTTP/ in Active Directory.
3) I use this procedure to find the duplicate entry 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321044

4) I use Active Directory User and Computer to remove the duplicate entry:
a) Open ADUAC
b) View->Advanced Features
c) Open the object with duplicate entry
d) Open the Attribute Editor
e) select servicePrincipalName and delete the entry
f)disable again kerberso logging

Bye
  Francesco